# Arraylist Object not finding method

Tags: java

I am creating an arraylist of objects and trying to print them out. However, when I go to print it is not finding the method.

Researched arraylist Objects and copied some other code. I just can not seem to find the problem with my code.

```
public class Main{

   public static void main(String[] args){

  List<PhoneBook> users = new ArrayList<>();

  users.add(new PhoneBook("Paul", 4129991));
  users.add(new PhoneBook("Kelly", 5702135));

  for(int i = 0; i<users.size(); i++){
     System.out.println("PhoneBook " + PhoneBook.getName());
      }
   }
}




class PhoneBook{

  private String name; 
  private int phoneNumber;

public PhoneBook(String name, int phoneNumber){
   this.name = name;
   this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}


   public String getName(){
     return name;
 }

 public int getPhoneNumber(){
   return phoneNumber;
 }

 public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
 }

 public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber){
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
 }



}
```

Comment: Change `PhoneBook.getName()` to `users.get(i).getName()`. There is no `static` method `getName()` on `PhoneBook`, and you can also look at it this way: you're looping over a list of multiple users, but you're not in any way telling the compiler which user from the list you want to get the name for. That can't be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a problem because your `users` data structure is an `ArrayList` of `PhoneBook` objects, which means you should be attempting to manipulate elements within the `ArrayList` as opposed to manipulating a `PhoneBook` object which does not exist.

Change your existing code from:

```
for(int i = 0; i<users.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("PhoneBook " + PhoneBook.getName());
}
```

to:

```
for(int i = 0; i<users.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("PhoneBook " + users.get(i).getName());
}
```

Your code should be iterating through each element of the `ArrayList` by index (your `i` variable) and getting the name from each item within that `ArrayList`. `PhoneBook` is the name of a class, but does not refer to the elements of your data structure. Although those elements are instances of `PhoneBook`, invoking the class name doesn't refer to anything in particular, which is why the compiler complains.

Comment: "users(i) gives a compile error" to avoid such problems use for-each like `for (PhoneBook user : users){ ... user.getName(); ...}`. Also that list probably shouldn't be called `users` but `phoneBooks` or maybe even `PhoneBook` shouldn't be called that way but rather `PhoneBookEntry` since it doesn't contain like standard phone book information about many people but it is entry about single person.